# Trigger an event when mediaPlayer stops

Tags: android, events, audio, android-mediaplayer

I am making an app that uses sound effects. I would like to know how i can detect when a sound has finished playing and trigger an event .

i tried this :

```
 player = new MediaPlayer();
    if (player != null) {
        player.reset();
        player.release();
    }

    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

            sonar.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sonar_off);
            stopPlay();
        }
    });

        if(state==1){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonar_slow);
        }else if(state==2){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonar_medium);
        }else if(state==3){
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonar_fast);
        }
         try{
             player.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        player.start();
```

Comment: Do you know the length of the audio file?

Comment: i have multiple audio files with different lengths

Comment: You should really read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)) before posting.

Comment: player.prepare() must NOT be called, when using create with sound Res Id, since it already has prepare in the code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set an OnCompleteListener() to the player object. The code for it is:

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
             { 
                "your code comes here" 
             }
});
```

Here the mPlayer is the object of the MediaPlayer which is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to play sounds, assuming you use the MediaPlayer class you could register a [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29)

Comment: He/she specified `MediaPlayer` in a tag so I'm guessing that'll work